# How to check whatever number user selected from dropdownlist , if its greater than Qty , display alert

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an input field in which I show the availability of a product. I also have a dropdown list where the user can choose how many product they want. Both values are saved to a database when the user hits the submit button.

I want to check if the number that was selected by the user in the dropdown list  is greater than the number the availability of the product.
If this is the case, on the submit, there should be a popup (alert) that says the selection is invalid.

Example:
Availability of the product is 50 
Selected value from the dropdown is 53

Alert ("You can choose btw 1-50").
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

View:

```
    @using Namespace.Models
    @model RMAHistory

    //Quantity
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Quantity </label>
    <input name="Antal" id="Antal" class="form-control border-input disabled" value="@string.Format("{0:N0}", Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Quantity)">
      </div>
    </div>

    //DropDown
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Number of returning</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRMAAntal, Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }), "- Select - ", new { @class = "form-control border-input" })
    </div>
     </div>

<button id="btn" type="submit"  class="btn">Send</button>
```

Controller & RMAHistory ViewModel:

```
public class RMAHistory
{
    public List<SelectListItem> RMAAntal { set; get; }
    public int? SelectedRMAAntal { set; get; }

    public string AntalRMA { get; set; }
    public string Antal { get; set; }

}


public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(RMAHistory model,string SelectedRMAAntal){
    var RMA = new RMA_History
    {

        Antal = model.Antal,
        AntalRMA = SelectedRMAAntal
    };

    db.RMA_History.Add(RMA);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return myfunction();
        });

        function myfunction() {
            var model = {
                Antal: $("#Antal").val(),
                SelectedRMAAntal: $("#SelectedRMAAntal").val()
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Account/ProcessRequestRMA",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {       
                    Antal: model.Antal,
                    SelectedRMAAntal : model.SelectedRMAAntal

                },

                success: function (status) {
                    if (status) {
                        status.Antal = model.Antal;
                        status.AntalRMA = model.SelectedRMAAntal;
                        console.log("Send");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Something Wrong");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: IF you already know the quantity available when populating your View, why not just limit your drop down list to hold only values up to the Maximum? Otherwise, when the user selects a specific item, you could use Ajax to grab the quantity for that item and then populate the drop down so it only holds values up to the max.

Comment: @RyanWilson dats good question , would you please tell me how can i do that! :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So you have a disabled input control which displays the quantity you have of an item, and the drop down is used for selecting how many of that item the user wants to return? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes exactly and DDL just contains numbers (123....)

Comment: wouldn't something like this work?    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRMAAntal, Enumerable.Range(0, Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Quantity).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }), "- Select - ", new { @class = "form-control border-input" })

Comment: I agree, I think maybe @Fran's approach is what you may want to use.

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) @Fran , Yes its works fine , if you like post your answer and i will mark as right answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your range up so that the max is the available quantity from your model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRMAAntal, Enumerable.Range(0, Model.InvoiceDetailsSingelLine.Quantity).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }), "- Select - ", new { @class = "form-control border-input" })
```